# Contextual generation of JSON in Haskell using Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have a complex nested data structure that I would like to convert to JSON in different ways depending on some provided context. My use case is that my server contains the full state of the world state, but depending on which client is asking for it I want to provide a redacted copy. Ideally I'd like to write something like:

```
instance ToJSON MyNestedType where
  toJSON x = do
    currentUser <- ask

    return $ if owner x == currentUser then (defaultToJson x) else (toJSON "REDACTED")

encodeWithReader (UserId 123) myDataStructure
```

Looking at the type of [`toJSON :: a -> Value`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.3.1.1/docs/Data-Aeson.html#v:toJSON) this doesn't appear to be possible with plain Aeson. What would be a good option for doing this? A couple of options I was thinking about:

- Implementing my own typeclass `ToJSONReader`, and having a default implementation that simply passes through to `ToJSON` and overriding for the types that need redacting. Something like (this doesn't compile, just pseudocode. I don't actually know how to make this work.):

  ```
  class ToJSONReader a where
    toJSONReader :: a -> Reader b Value

  instance ToJSON a => ToJSONReader a where
    toJSONReader x = return $ toJSON x

  instance ToJSONReader MyNestedType where
    toJSONReader x = do
      currentUser <- ask
      return $ if owner x == currentUser then (toJSON x) else (toJSON "REDACTED")
  ```
- Rather than use `encode` directly, use `toJSON` to get the intermediate `Value` then write code to redact that (kind of gross).
- Extend my type to include tags for redaction, then pre-process a copy of the type before converting to JSON.
- Create a new complex parent type `RedactedMyType` and duplicate the structure of the original type, but subbing in redacted options in the ADT as needed. Pretty gross also.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Everyone gets so hung up on only using `FromJSON` and `ToJSON` that they forget they can just write whatever the heck functions they want and call them whatever they want. It's weird, and it only seems to happen with aeson. I don't get it. If you want an extra argument to your JSON encoder, *just write an encoder that takes an extra argument and don't call it `toJSON`*. (I'm not criticizing you -- it seems to be a common pitfall, so somewhere along the way the information out there on how to use aeson has screwed up, not you. I just don't understand where.)

Comment: This is kind of where I was going with the ToJSONReader idea. Probably people get hung up on it because you get `ToJSON` instances for free with generics, and it's non-obvious how I would get that same thing doing it myself. In my case, I have tens of types in a big complex data structure, I'm not particularly keen to write out full implementations of all of them myself. Perhaps an example of that in Aeson documentation would be helpful? (I mean, I know in theory I must be able to write a generic derivation, I've just got no idea how to do it.)

Comment: @DanielWagner That's a fair notice, but often times people use Aeson indirectly by using some more complex framework that requires the proper Aeson instances for the data types.  It is in these situations where some of the trickier classes come in handy in my experience.